# Bar Chart, Displaying one bar on top of another

Tags: asp.net

I have a bar chart with two series both containing data points. Rendering the graph gives me an image looking like this.

[image: bar chartIs]

I would like the yellow bar to go on top of the blue, so that for Test1 it will reach up to 40. Is this possible?

This is my code

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
    <Series>
    <asp:Series Name="Initial" YValueType="Int32">
        <Points>
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Test 1" YValues="10" />
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Test 2" YValues="20" />
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Test 3" YValues="30" />
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Test 4" YValues="40" />
        </Points>
    </asp:Series>
    <asp:Series Name="Adding" YValueType="Int32">
        <Points>
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Test 1" YValues="30" />
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Test 2" YValues="20" />
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Test 3" YValues="20" />
            <asp:DataPoint AxisLabel="Test 4" YValues="10" />
        </Points>
    </asp:Series>
    </Series>
    <ChartAreas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
    </ChartAreas>
</asp:Chart>
```

Comment: Are you looking for stacked chart? http://www.jqplot.com/tests/bar-charts.php

Comment: You need to create a chart type StackedColumn100 There is some great examples on the download page found at http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418

Comment: Marvelous resource Kevin Kunderman! If you would like to add that as an answer I would be happy to select it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a chart type `StackedColumn100` Here is a [link](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4418) to a great example of what is possible with not only stacked charts but on  MS Charts Controls  as a whole